# Scala read file and load in list as json object

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

I am trying to read a csv file using Scala and store the output as a list of Json (`list(json.obj)`).

Here is my code:

```
def index = Action {
  Logger.info("Application startup...")
  var posts = List(Json.obj())
  var finalPost = List(Json.obj())
  val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile("/Users/manujkathuria/a.csv")
  for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
    val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    posts = List(
      Json.obj(
        "name" -> cols(0),
        "age" -> cols(1),
        "job" -> cols(2)
      ))
    finalPost +: posts
  }
  bufferedSource.close
}
```

So my target is to store the data which I read from a.csv file and load it in the list of `jsonObjects` which I will use later for loading into MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks @marcospereira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid the use of variables when you can. I think a better solution could be

```
def index = Action {
  Logger.info("Application startup...")
  val json = parse("/Users/manujkathuria/a.csv")
  ... 
}
def parse(file:String): List[Json] = {
  val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile(file)
  try {
    bufferedSource.getLines().map(line => {
      val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
      Json.obj(
        "name" -> cols(0),
        "age" -> cols(1),
        "job" -> cols(2)
      )
    }).toList
  } finally
    bufferedSource.close
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mikel its working now. Thanks for your suggestions.

```
val surveyDB = parse("/Users/manujkathuria/a.csv")

def parse(file: String): List[JsObject] = {

     val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(file)
     try {
     bufferedSource.getLines().map(line => {
     val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
     Json.obj("name" -> cols(0), "age" -> cols(1), "job" -> cols(2))
     }).toList
     } finally
    bufferedSource.close
 }
```